# gem5: how to use openssl library in SimlationObject?

Tags: openssl, gem5

I'm try to use Openssl library for gem5.

My SimObject code include two header on Openssl.

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
```

But there is a link error.
Error message is

```
undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new'
undefined reference to `EVP_aes_128_ctr'
```

What we have already done

1. apt install libssl-dev
2. apt install libcrypto++6 libcrypto++6-dbg libcrypto++-dev
3. Added to SConstruct in "if main['GCC']" block
   main.Append(LDFLAGS =["-L/usr/local/ssl/include"])
   main.Append(LDLIBS=["-lcrypto"])

evp.h,and aes.h are in /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl

We would be grateful for your help!

```
$ openssl version -a

OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
built on: Mon Aug 23 17:02:39 2021 UTC
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(int) blowfish(ptr)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -Wa,--noexecstack -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/openssl-JWge0V/openssl-1.1.1f=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DOPENSSL_TLS_SECURITY_LEVEL=2 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've installed `libcrypto` through `apt-get`, it should be in a system library path known to `scons`, so you shouldn't need to append to `LDFLAGS`.

You need to link against `libcrypto` within the `SConstruct` file. Change `main.Append(LDLIBS=["-lcrypto"])` for `main.Append(LIBS=["crypto"])`. See https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/ch04s02.html for details.

PS: you can pass `--verbose` to `scons` to verify the linker command uses `-lcrypto` correctly.

Comment: thanks to reply, but your idea doesn't solve my problem.
So, i doesn't use openssl lib......